# Fill in missing values based on series and populate second row based on previous or next row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv with 4 columns. The file contains some missing rows based on the series.

Input:-

```
No  A   B   C
1   10  50  12
3   40  50  12
4   20  60  15
6   80  80  18
```

Output:-

```
No  A   B   C
1   10  50  12
2   10  50  12
3   40  50  12
4   20  60  15
5   20  60  15
6   80  80  18
```

I need python and pandas code to generate the above output.

Answer (score 1):

Use if `No` is column - create index by `No` and [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by `range` with all possible values:

```
v = range(df['No'].min(), df['No'].max() + 1)
df1 = df.set_index('No').reindex(v, method='ffill').reset_index()
print (df1)
   No   A   B   C
0   1  10  50  12
1   2  10  50  12
2   3  40  50  12
3   4  20  60  15
4   5  20  60  15
5   6  80  80  18
```

Use if `No` is index solution is changed a bit:

```
v = range(df.index.min(), df.index.max() + 1)
df1 = df.reindex(v, method='ffill')
print (df1)
     A   B   C
No            
1   10  50  12
2   10  50  12
3   40  50  12
4   20  60  15
5   20  60  15
6   80  80  18
```

Comment: when I am using this statement v = range(df['No'].min(), df['No'].max() + 1) it is giving me error-TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Comment: @ankitsaxena - Do you use `pyspark` ?

Comment: its giving this output-Column<b'No'>

Comment: @ankitsaxena - So problem is my solution working for pandas, not for pyspark. Problem is you forget for tag `pyspark`, so both answers are for pandas.

Comment: So Can you please provide this solution for pyspark as well. thanks

Comment: @ankitsaxena - Problem is not idea. So is necessary post new question with tag `pyspark`

Comment: Thanks, Jezrael I will post a new question for that

Comment: Hi Jezrael below is a link for another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60681807/fill-in-missing-values-based-on-series-and-populate-second-row-based-on-previous

Answer (score 0):

Create a dataframe of your missing rows

```
missing_list = [[i] + [pd.np.nan]*(df.shape[1] - 1) for i in range(df.No.min(), df.No.max()) if i not in df.No]
missing_df = pd.DataFrame(missing_list, columns=df.columns)
```

Concat to original dataframe, sort and forward fill

```
pd.concat([df, missing_df]).sort_values('No').ffill()
```